# Empty sessions on local xampp server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, xampp, localhost

I'm having an issue with sessions on a PHP site I'm running locally on xampp. I have a login page that creates a session and redirects to the logged in area. In the logged in area, there are checks to see if 1) a session variable is empty and 2) the info matches the database.

When I log in, I fail the first step, so the session variable is empty. The exact code for the check is below:

```
if(!empty($this->session->userdata['auth'])){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

I'm sent to the logged in area from the login page, so I think it at least tried to create the session before it redirects me, but I'm not really sure how to check to be certain.

I have recently re-installed the operating system and all programs on my computer, including xampp, so I am assuming that the problem is there. This exact code is running fine on a remote server and was running fine on my old local system in xampp.

The code is written in CodeIgniter and the session library is loaded.

- PHP version: 7.1.4
- CodeIgniter version: 3.1.0
- Xampp version: 3.2.2

Session variables from config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Cookie variables from config.php:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

EDIT:

This is how the session is set:

```
$sessionArr = array(
    'userId'=> $userDetails->userId,
    'username'=> $userDetails->username,
    'email'=> $userDetails->email,
    'userType'=> $userDetails->userType
    );
$this->session->set_userdata('auth',$sessionArr);
```

Comment: hi, if you [read doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data) you can do this `if(!is_null($this->session->auth)){//exist}else{//redirect}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this code now and I am getting the same issue. I think the problem is that the session isn't saving properly on my localhost because it is running without problems on a remote host, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Why don't you check the cookies are being sent/returned, if a session file is created, if there are any errors or warnings being raised by php?

Comment: I know now that session files are being created. I'm not getting any errors or warnings by PHP, except when I force the script to pass the test. Then I get a warning that I'm "Trying to get property of non-object" because the session is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to uninstall xampp and install a previous version. I had tried re-installing the same version before without success.

Answer (score 1):

Store sessions in your project.

Use APPPATH or FCPATH I store min in cache folder.

`$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';`

OR

`$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . '/application/cache/sessions/';`

make sure folder permission 0700

And use `()` not `[]`

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('userID')) {
    redirect('somecontroller')
}
```

I am not sure how you set sessions though set sessions something like

```
$sessionArr = array(
    'userId'=> $userDetails->userId,
    'username'=> $userDetails->username,
    'email'=> $userDetails->email,
    'userType'=> $userDetails->userType
    );
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArr);
```

Comment: Thank you for multiple suggestions! I really appreciate the help! I created a cache folder inside the application folder and used APPATH in the save_path. I now know that it is saving session files there. I've also double checked the file permissions and I've corrected the parentheses. I'll add an edit above to show how the sessions are set.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the last and most important sentence in my answer: the problem persists even with all the suggestions implemented.

Comment: @Thomas you have 'auth' like `$this->session->set_userdata('auth',$sessionArr);` try with out `$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArr);`

Comment: Then use like `$this->session->userdata('userID')`

Comment: @Thomas I updated my answer http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Comment: I tried removing the auth and instead using the array directly in userdata, but that didn't solve the problem. The thing I find weird is that the exact same code runs well on another server.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with some earlier version of Codeigniter 3 and this is a [bug](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4830) already reported in their website.The underlying session bug has been fixed on:

- 3.1.2
- 3.1.3
- 3.1.4

So in the latest version of Codeigniter 3 this issue doesn't happen.

#### Solutions:

If you are already in a faulty version codeigniter consider replacing system folder with **latest** version's one. Version 3.1.7 at the time writing this.